# convert rows/table records to json document in sql server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

the following is the sample data which is an input

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#store_data') is not null
drop table #store_data

create table #store_data ([key] nvarchar(max),[value] nvarchar(max),storeid varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('sid','1','1')
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('bid','3','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('time','2019-01-01','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('que','apple','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('sid','2','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('bid','5','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('hrs','6','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('dat','pine','2');

select * from #store_data
```

the following is the result required

```
[{
"sid"="1",
"bid"="3",
"time"="2019-01-01"
"que"="apple"},
{"sid"="2",
"bid"="5",
"hrs"="6",
"dat"="pine"
}]
```

the following is the query which i have tried

```
select [key],[value] from #store_data for json path
```

expected results were not achieved.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact, that **there is no implicit sort order!** Without an outermost `ORDER BY` this can work hundred times, pass all internal tests, but will return rubbish in production. It is nothing then random if `bid=3` appears in the first or in the second JSON object.

Comment: I have updated my answer @Shnugo...given by PSK...I have used loops to get the result set...but i felt is there another way for retrieving in same order

Comment: Loop or not: A SQL-Server is not sorted the way you insert your data. Any `SELECT` without an outermost `ORDER BY` can return in any random sort order. If you want to persist the sort order, the easiest is to add an `IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note, you can't get with direct query, you have to first `PIVOT` on `storeid`.

You can try like following query.

```
select sid, bid, time,que, hrs,dat 
from #store_data src
pivot
(
  MAX([value])
  for [key] in (sid, bid, time,que, hrs,dat)
) piv
for json auto
```

**Full Example**

```
 if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#store_data') is not null
 drop table #store_data

create table #store_data ([key] nvarchar(max),[value] nvarchar(max),storeid varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('sid','1','1')
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('bid','3','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('time','2019-01-01','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('que','apple','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('sid','2','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('bid','5','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('hrs','6','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('dat','pine','2');

select sid, bid, time,que, hrs,dat 
from #store_data src
pivot
(
  MAX([value])
  for [key] in (sid, bid, time,que, hrs,dat)
) piv
for json auto
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "sid": "1",
    "bid": "3",
    "time": "2019-01-01",
    "que": "apple"
  },
  {
    "sid": "2",
    "bid": "5",
    "hrs": "6",
    "dat": "pine"
  }
]
```

**Online Demo:**

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0eccddd064b37f6c17f4139927678864)

**Edit:**

`PIVOT` is automatically ordering on `stroeid` `ASC` without specifying any order. In case you want to change it to a different order let say `DESC stroeid`, in that case you can change the query as following.

```
select sid, bid, time,que, hrs,dat 
from #store_data src
pivot
(
  MAX([value])
  for [key] in (sid, bid, time,que, hrs,dat)
) piv
order by storeid desc
for json auto
```

Comment: Hi, Although this might be the correct approach, we cannot get tired to point to the fact, that **there is no implicit sort order!** Without an outermost `ORDER BY` this can work hundred times, pass all internal tests, but will return rubbish in production. It is nothing then random if `bid=3` appears in the first or in the second JSON object.

Comment: Hi @Shnugo , I am not sure if I am getting the point. Your comment is beyond my knowledge. Can you please explain it little more or some sample data where it can re produce the scenario

Comment: Okay, I was a bit to fast, because I did not see the `storeid` on the very first sight, which is included by `SELECT *`. Together with this information, the objects will get the correct values (as group). Without this `storeid` as a part of the final JSON it still holds true, that you have no guarantee, which JSON-object will appear first and which will appear second. But this is not really against your approach (+1 from my side)

Comment: I am happy that you have identified the point "order of display" @Shnugo.....I request PSK and Shnugo is there way in the query without using while loop to display the results in same order.

Comment: @Smart003, i have edited the answer, you can have a look.

Comment: @PSK, althoug the `PIVOT` will implicitly sort your set, only the outermost `SELECT` counts. This will return as expected 1 million time, but the outermost `SELECT` (forming the JSON) can by any time decide to return differently. If you want to be sure about the sort order, you should always add a final `ORDER BY`...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
drop table if exists #store_data;

create table #store_data ([key] nvarchar(max),[value] nvarchar(max),storeid varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('sid','1','1')
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('bid','3','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('time','2019-01-01','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('que','apple','1');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('sid','2','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('bid','5','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('hrs','6','2');
INSERT INTO #store_data VALUES ('dat','pine','2');

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ColumnNames = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + [key] + ']'
        FROM #store_data
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
   ,1
   ,1
   ,''
);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
select ' + @ColumnNames + '
from #store_data
PIVOT 
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [key] IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')
) PVT
FOR JSON PATH;
';


EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

[image]

Change to `SELECT *` in order to get the `storeid` in the JSON object, too. Also, in SQL Server 2017 you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to concatenate the keys.

Comment: The query is tagged `SQL Server 2017`

Comment: Yes, that's why I am saying that he can use `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Why post the XML concatenation technique then? It hides the *actual* solution, which is to PIVOT the data before converting them to JSON

Comment: Because it will work on earlier versions and its possible other users to see this question and not have `STRING_AGG` function.

Comment: You might read my comment below the question about the *non-existant implict sort order*..

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, you are right. That's why I pointed we can use `SELECT *` in order to get the `storeid` in each object. It seems normal to have it there, because it is used to group the data.

Comment: You are right, I added a comment to the other answer. +1 form my side here as well